# Flutter Firebase: Get imageUrl from firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I stream a list of Items with a ListViewBuilder and I `setState` upon `onTap`. I can get all the data but I can't seem to get the app to display the image.

```
QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? selectedUser;

StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("collection")
                    .orderBy("FirstName", descending: false)
                    .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot){
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text("Error");
                  } 
                   if (snapshot.hasData){
                    return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                     itemBuilder: (context, index){
                       final data = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                        return ListTile (
                           onTap: (){ setState((){
                             selectedUser = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                            });
                            },
                           title: Row(
                                    children: [
                                         Text(data.get('Name')), //this works
                                         Text(data.get('Pic')), //it displays the image url verywell. 
                                         Center(
                                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                                    radius: 15,
                                                    backgroundImage:
                                                    NetworkImage(data.get('Pic')), //It however does not display the image.
                                  ),
                                           )
                                       ]
                                 )
                          );
                      }
                   )
                   }
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text("");
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text(""),
                    );
                  }
                }
               ),
//This is on a different widget but in the same class.
Container(
  child: Column(children:
          [
        Text("${selectedUser?["FirstName"] ?? ""}   "${selectedUser?["Pic"] ?? ""}"), //This also displays the name and the image URL
        CircleAvatar(radius: 100,
                     backgroundImage: NetworkImage(selectedUser?["ProfilePic"] ?? ""), //However this does not display the image either.
                    )
   ]
  )
  )
```

PS: This is a web App so I'm using chrome. And this is for the admin section.
Retrieving the same image worked well on Android and IOS apps.

I see this on the debug console:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ImageCodecException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed to detect image file format using the file header.
File header was [0x3c 0x21 0x44 0x4f 0x43 0x54 0x59 0x50 0x45 0x20].
Image source: encoded image bytes
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49  throw_
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/image_web_codecs.dart 37:7                       create
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54            runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5            _async
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/image_web_codecs.dart 22:46                      create
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/image.dart 13:34                                 skiaInstantiateImageCodec
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/renderer.dart 198:15                             instantiateImageCodec
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54            runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5            _async
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/renderer.dart 193:41                             instantiateImageCodec
lib/ui/painting.dart 505:28                                                   instantiateImageCodecWithSize
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54            runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5            _async
lib/ui/painting.dart 500:44                                                   instantiateImageCodecWithSize
packages/flutter/src/painting/binding.dart 182:15                             instantiateImageCodecWithSize
packages/flutter/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart 184:22                  _loadAsync
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                          runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 156:18                                    handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 840:44                                    handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 869:13                                    _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 641:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 715:7                                     callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:15           <fn>
Image provider: NetworkImage("", scale: 1)
Image key: NetworkImage("", scale: 1)
```

I don't however understand it